# How to use GitHub action secrets in a reusable workflow?

Tags: github-actions, github-secret

I have a number of GitHub actions that interact with Azure using the `az` command line, so I figured I'd try to write a reusable workflow to log into Azure. I have been following this guide: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows

When I run my caller workflow, I get this error:

> Error: .../log-into-azure/action.yml (Line: 21, Col: 14): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression: secrets.DEV_APPLICATION_ID

My caller workflow contains this:

```
    - name: Azure login with elevated permissions
      uses: ./.github/actions/log-into-azure
      with:
        secrets: inherit
```

My reusable workflow looks like this:

```
name: Log into Azure
description: 'Log into Azure.'

on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      DEV_APPLICATION_ID:
        required: true
      DEV_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET:
        required: true
      TENANT_ID:
        required: true

jobs:
  azure-login:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, ubuntu-latest]
    steps:

      - name: Azure login with elevated permissions
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          az login --service-principal -u "${{ secrets.DEV_APPLICATION_ID }}" -p "${{ secrets.DEV_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET }}" --tenant "${{ secrets.TENANT_ID }}"
```

I have also tried to list the secrets explicitly in the caller workflow (instead of using `secrets: inherit`) like this:

```
    - name: Azure login with elevated permissions
      uses: ./.github/actions/log-into-azure
      with:
        secrets:
          DEV_APPLICATION_ID: ${{ secrets.DEV_APPLICATION_ID }}
          DEV_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET: ${{ secrets.DEV_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET }}
          TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.TENANT_ID }}
```

... but that gave the following error message:

> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/deploy.yml (Line: 60, Col: 11): A mapping was not expected

**EDIT 1**

I have also tried to put `secrets` on the same indentation level as `uses` in my caller workflow, like this (lines 63-65):

```
    - name: Azure login with elevated permissions
      uses: ./.github/actions/log-into-azure
      secrets: inherit
```

That also fails:

> Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/deploy.yml#L65
> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/deploy.yml (Line: 65, Col: 7): Unexpected value 'secrets'

Likewise if I do this:

```
    - name: Azure login with elevated permissions
      uses: ./.github/actions/log-into-azure
      secrets:
        DEV_APPLICATION_ID: ${{ secrets.DEV_APPLICATION_ID }}
        DEV_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET: ${{ secrets.DEV_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET }}
        TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.TENANT_ID }}
```

I get the exact same error message.

**EDIT 2**

Here is a minimal working example of my whole caller workflow:

```
name: Deploy to persistent environment

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy-kms-to-persistent-environment:
    name: 'Deploy KMS to ${{ github.event.inputs.deployment_target}} from Git commit: ${{ github.sha }}'
    runs-on: [self-hosted, 3shape-ubuntu-latest]

    steps:

    - name: Azure login with elevated permissions
      uses: ./.github/actions/log-into-azure
      secrets: inherit
```

Comment: Scroll down to step 3 of the documentation you've linked. `with` and `secrets` are separate config blocks; the way you have it, `secrets` is part of `with`.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't help. I've updated the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows), your problem occurs due to the indentation in the workflow calling the reusable workflow.

You are informing secrets that way:

```
      uses: ...
      with:
        secrets:
```

And it should be using `secrets` at the same level as `with`:

```
      uses: ...
      with:
      secrets:
```

Using your example, both options should look like this:

```
    - uses: ./.github/actions/log-into-azure
      secrets: inherit
```

and

```
    - uses: ./.github/actions/log-into-azure
      secrets:
          DEV_APPLICATION_ID: ${{ secrets.DEV_APPLICATION_ID }}
          DEV_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET: ${{ secrets.DEV_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET }}
          TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.TENANT_ID }}
```

*Note: In both case, `with` should be use for **inputs**, and not for **secrets**.*

**Example:**

```
    uses: ...
    with:
      input1: value1
    secrets:
      secret1: ${{ secrets.SECRET1 }}
```

---

Moreover, note that you don't specify the runner and steps when calling a reusable workflows. You just specify the reusable workflow path with the `uses` field (with the ref), as you already configured the runner and the steps **IN** the reusable workflow.

In your case, it seems you're calling an action in the workflow, not a reusable workflow.

**Example (compare to your workflow in the EDIT 2):**

```
name: Deploy to persistent environment

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  job1:
    uses: owner/repo/.github/workflows/log-into-azure.yml@main #you need the ref here
    secrets: inherit
```

Comment: Thanks. But I tried that. That gives a syntax error. I have updated my OP with the code I used and the error message I get.

Comment: Are you calling the reusable workflow in a job step? (could you also share the whole workflow calling the reusable in your question to try reproducing the error?)

Comment: Minimal failing example added to OP.

Comment: Here is the problem: You don't specify the runner and steps when calling a reusable workflows. You just specify the reusable workflow path with the `uses` field, as you already configured the runner and the steps IN the reusable workflow. [Example](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#passing-inputs-and-secrets-to-a-reusable-workflow)

Comment: Besides, looking at your example, it seems you're calling a local `action` in the workflow, not a `reusable workflow`, the syntax isn't the same.

Comment: Ohhhhh, `uses` needs to be at job level and not at step level! That makes sense. All right. Thanks.